# SVN Reset Certificate Information

Tags: svn, certificate

I'm building some code that requires some input files to be checked out from a public server. The instructions that I'm following state that:

> **When contacting** the Subversion server **for the first time**, the following certificate message **will *likely* be generated**:
>
> ```
> Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn-ccsm-release.cgd.ucar.edu:443':
>  - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
>    fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
>  - The certificate hostname does not match.
>  - The certificate has expired.
> Certificate information:
>  - Hostname: localhost.localdomain
>  - Valid: from Feb 20 23:32:25 2008 GMT until Feb 19 23:32:25 2009 GMT
>  - Issuer: SomeOrganizationalUnit, SomeOrganization, SomeCity, SomeState, --
>  - Fingerprint: 86:01:bb:a4:4a:e8:4d:8b:e1:f1:01:dc:60:b9:96:22:67:a4:49:ff
> (R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?
> ```
>
> **After accepting the certificate**, the repository **will request a
>   username and password**. Be aware that the request may set current
>   machine login id as the default username. Once correctly entered, the
>   username and password will be cached in a protected subdirectory of
>   the user's home directory so that repeated entry of this information
>   will not required for a given machine.

This never happens for me. I was not prompted for the Certificate Information nor username or password the *first* time. Instead in the middle of the build upon checking out the required data I am asked to type a password I never set.

Is there any way to reset my Certificate Information or set up a password that I chose?